# Is there a free summary of the clans in The Ninja Crusade online?

Tags: online-resources, wu-xing-the-ninja-crusade

My group is currently contemplating on what game to play next. One that came up is The Ninja Crusade. Even though when I searched the net I did find info about the system itself (which sounds nice), I found no summary about what the clans are each about. (I found only a few comments about a few clans; that there are 12 in the main rules book; and, from what I read in those comments about those few clans, they reminded me quite a bit of the clans found in Naruto.)

Thus I'm wondering: is there any freely-available info about the clans, such as a short summary about what each clan is about, fluffwise and also mechanically?

Comment: Could you describe more what searching you did? I'm finding descriptions of the clans just fine, but since I can't tell if you've seen these pages (and decided they were too short “comments”) or not, I can't tell if pointing at them is a real answer or not.

Comment: I didnt find anything about the clans. mostly a short summary what they are about and what their powers are about (for example the only one I know are those moon clans who have bonded with animals-dogs specifically and their powers build on this connection. Things like that. Then I read something that some clan is long living and I think poisoners or healers or something like that )

Comment: @SevenSidedDie quite possibly they are viable. if you dont want to post a possibly too short answer you could post the links as comment and I look if it is what I meant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not certain what you or @SevenSidedDie have found, so I'm going to dump what I have found.

For (brief) clan descriptions:

- [Wu Xing In Brief](http://thirdeyegames.net/sheets/wuxing/WX-Inbrief.pdf).
- [RPG.net review](http://www.rpg.net/reviews/archive/14/14862.phtml)

The [Goodies](http://thirdeyegames.net/goodies/) section of the official site has some pre-generated characters (which can give you an idea of what the clan-specific wushu are about).

The [Let's Study from Philgamer](https://philgamer.wordpress.com/category/roleplaying-games/wu-xing/page/2/), combined with the RPG.net review gave me a better understanding of the system. I preferred Philgamer's take, because it took it's time to look at the different bits & pieces to see what glued together and what was a bit wibbly-wobbly.

Comment: The first link and the rpg net review both contain brief clan summaries maybe you can add that tot he answer that those two contain clan summaries? Else: Nice find

Comment: yepp tnx that makes it more clear